# CK Editor - Image paste from Ms Word

Tags: image, ckeditor, copy-paste

I'am copying a page from MS word  doc to ck editor which has an image. In Ck editor all contents are displayed except the Image. Also i am getting an error "Because of your browser security settings, the editor is not able to access your clipboard data directly. You are required to paste it again in this window".

Answer (score 2):

bcz there is setting for copy & pase in fckeditor 
if you want to allow copy from word u have to change below line in fckconfig.js file

To

```
FCKConfig.ForcePasteAsPlainText = false;
```

Comment: I am using ckeditor latest version, i could not find the same parameter in config.js. Where to set this one for CKeditor?

Answer (score 0):

Only IE 11 is able to correctly paste the images as well as the contents from Word, the rest of the browsers only create a reference to the local file.

In order to take advantage of that info you can use the [Images From Word](http://www.uritec.es/portal/seccion.aspx?N=67) plugin to detect and upload those images to the server.